# Ionic capacitor Android app cannot access internet

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

This is the versions and configurations as follows,

```
// package.json

 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    ....
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.1.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "^2.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.7",
    ....
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
  },

// confgi.xml
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />

// AndroidManifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.ssp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

       .....

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Camera, Photos, input file -->
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Geolocation API -->
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <!-- Network API -->
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- Navigator.getUserMedia -->
    <!-- Video -->
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <!-- Audio -->
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>

</manifest>
```

And have build the signed apk (production enabled) using Android studio 4.0, and once i tried the apk on devices, it works fine with `Android 6.0, 7.0, 8.0` application is fetching data from server. But when i try to it on `Android 10.0` it cannot access internet.

Any help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android 9 and newer disable http connections by default, so if you want to allow http connections you can add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Or if you don't want to allow all http traffic, but just a few urls, check security-config docs: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted

Answer (score 0):

You should be add to the manifest the below code AndroidManifest.xml
`<application  ...android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" ..>`
and add a new file network_security_config.xml in folder xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">yourdomain.com</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">your.second.domain</domain>
  </domain-config>
 </network-security-config>`
```