# ionic android platform cannot communicate with backend over http

Tags: android, ionic-framework, amazon-ec2, capacitor

I'm testing communication between an ionic android app and backend (Amazon EC2 server).

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

service used to Login:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, shareReplay, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';


export interface Login {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  userType: string;
}

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(): Observable<any> {

    // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
    let loginData: Login =  {
      email : 'test@gmail.com',
      password : 'Test',
      userType : 'testUser'
    };

    return this.http.post('http://amazon-elastic-ip:8011/authentication-api/users/login', loginData, httpOptions).pipe(
        shareReplay(),
        tap(), catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('error', JSON.stringify(error));
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
          `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
          `body was: ${JSON.stringify(error.error.message)}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
        'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }
}
```

Home.page.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {LoginService} from '../services/login.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  data;
  error;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Initializing HomePage');
  }

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
  }


  login() {
    this.loginService.login().subscribe(data => this.data = JSON.stringify(data));
    setTimeout (() => {
      this.error = sessionStorage.getItem('error');
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

and Home.html:

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-header collapse="condense">
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title size="large">Blank</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>  

  <ion-button (click)="login()">Login</ion-button>
  <h1>data</h1>
  {{data}}
  <h1>Error</h1>
  {{error}}
</ion-content>
```

Incoming rules to reach my backend server, port 8011 are: 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 (from anywhere)

When I debug the application with the following command:

```
ionic capacitor run android -l --host=MY-HOST-IP
```

The application works fine in my device, and I can get token from Backend after login.

But when I run it using:

```
 ionic capacitor run android
```

I have communication timeout and the following error:

```
error: {isTrusted: true}
isTrusted: true
headers: {normalizedNames: {}, lazyUpdate: null, headers: {}}
headers: {}
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: {}
message: "Http failure response for http://amazon-elastic-ip:8011/authentication-api/users/login: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://amazon-elastic-ip:8011/authentication-api/users/login"
```

It seems that the server doesn't accept communication with my app, and when it tried to access the server from navigator in my device with ip address port 8011, I can get response from my REST API. Also I tried to add my device IP address to incoming rules port 8011, I got the same error.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62193416/1351469

Comment: By adding  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to the application tag in AndroidManifest.xml, the application works fine.  
Thanks !  :)